# How to toggle account sync at certain times?

Tags: sync, google-account, automation

I would like to pause the synchronization of my private account during work hours and sync the sync of my work account outside of my work hours. I don't want to use any special email client for that.

I remember this was possible some time ago, but is it still there? I tried looking for built in automations, IFTTT, even looked up apps that would allow that and found nothing.